# Python: Dictionary of list of lists

Tags: python, information-retrieval

```
def makecounter():
     return collections.defaultdict(int)

class RankedIndex(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._inverted_index = collections.defaultdict(list)
    self._documents = []
    self._inverted_index = collections.defaultdict(makecounter)


def index_dir(self, base_path):
    num_files_indexed = 0
    allfiles = os.listdir(base_path)
    self._documents = os.listdir(base_path)
    num_files_indexed = len(allfiles)
    docnumber = 0
    self._inverted_index = collections.defaultdict(list)

    docnumlist = []
    for file in allfiles: 
            self.documents = [base_path+file] #list of all text files
            f = open(base_path+file, 'r')
            lines = f.read()

            tokens = self.tokenize(lines)
            docnumber = docnumber + 1
            for term in tokens:  
                if term not in sorted(self._inverted_index.keys()):
                    self._inverted_index[term] = [docnumber]
                    self._inverted_index[term][docnumber] +=1                                           
                else:
                    if docnumber not in self._inverted_index.get(term):
                        docnumlist = self._inverted_index.get(term)
                        docnumlist = docnumlist.append(docnumber)
            f.close()
    print '\n \n'
    print 'Dictionary contents: \n'
    for term in sorted(self._inverted_index):
        print term, '->', self._inverted_index.get(term)
    return num_files_indexed
    return 0
```

I get index error on executing this code: list index out of range.

The above code generates a dictionary index that stores the 'term' as a key and the document numbers in which the term occurs as a list.
For ex: if the term 'cat' occurs in documents 1.txt, 5.txt and 7.txt the dictionary will have:
cat <- [1,5,7]

Now, I have to modify it to add term frequency, so if the word cat occurs twice in document 1, thrice in document 5 and once in document 7:
expected result:
term <-[[docnumber, term freq], [docnumber,term freq]] <--list of lists in a dict!!!
cat <- [[1,2],[5,3],[7,1]]

I played around with the code, but nothing works. I have no clue to modify this datastructure to achieve the above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, use a factory.  Start with:

```
def makecounter():
    return collections.defaultdict(int)
```

and later use

```
self._inverted_index = collections.defaultdict(makecounter)
```

and as the `for term in tokens:` loop,

```
        for term in tokens:  
                self._inverted_index[term][docnumber] +=1
```

This leaves in each `self._inverted_index[term]` a dict such as

```
{1:2,5:3,7:1}
```

in your example case.  Since you want instead in each `self._inverted_index[term]` a list of lists, then just after the end of the looping add:

```
self._inverted_index = dict((t,[d,v[d] for d in sorted(v)])
                            for t in self._inverted_index)
```

Once made (this way or any other -- I'm just showing a simple way to construct it!), this data structure will then actually be as awkward to use as you needlessly made it difficult to construct, of course (the dict of dict is much more useful and easy to use as well as to construct), but, hey, one's man meat &c;-).

Comment: I've made the changes suggested by you. I realize that your approach is much simpler and clear than implementing dict of list of lists. However, it's currently giving me an error, I've edited the code above.

Comment: @csguy, in your `indexdir` method (assuming it **is** one, your indentation as posted above is all wrong) you completely destroy whatever was previously assigned to `self._inverted_index` by assigning to it your previous, erroneous data structure, thus making your edits to your code totally and utterly irrelevant.  You **do** realize that when you do `self.a = b` it **just does not matter in the least any more** whatever, if anything, was previously assigned to `self.a`, right?!

Comment: I got what the problem was, but since I don't really understand your implementation, I decided to stick with my method i.e. dict of list of lists, even though it's overly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general algorithm you could use, but you will have adapt some of your code to it.
It produce a dict containing a dictionary of word counts for each file.

```
filedicts = {}
for file in allfiles:
  filedicts[file] = {}

  for term in terms:
    filedict.setdefault(term, 0)
    filedict[term] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could just create a simple class for (docname, frequency).

Then your dict could have lists of this new data type. You can do a list of lists, too, but a separate data type would be cleaner.